# Kafka silent failure

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I am trying to debug a connection issue with a Kafka server. Turns out that, using the latest version of the java client (3.6.1) this code fails silently:

```
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "8.8.8.8:9092");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "testGroup");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class.getName());
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class.getName());
        props.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
        consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(props);
        consumer.subscribe(List.of("non-existing-topic"));
        consumer.poll(Duration.ofSeconds(1));
```

The code above is connecting to a non-existing Kafka server (google DNS IPs), subscribing to a non existing topic and happily polling for messages that will never arrive. The code is taken from the textbook example, I would expect an exception to be thrown at consumer creation.
Is there anything suspicious? A setting that prevents failures to popup?
Connecting to the real Kafka server with `telnet` works fine and a message appears on the server logs regarding the failed attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure version matters; the KafkaConsumer will always assume the bootstrap servers are valid addresses, and continue to endlessly try to connect. A warning is logged (sounds like you are missing a log4j.properties if you see nothing?), but there is no exception thrown.

The same can be reproduced with `kafka-console-consumer`

Comment: Basically this is by design.
It makes really hard to understand what's going on when the connection succeeds but the consumer doesn't "register" with Kafka vs. when it is just delaying.